# VBA: Difference between & and +

Tags: vba, operators, concatenation

What is the difference between:

```
string1 + string2
```

and

```
string1 & string2
```

Are they equivalent? Why have two different symbols that do the same thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The expressions are the same as long as the operands are strings; if not, `+` might add them instead depending on type conversions. `&` guarantees you won't get anything except a string concatenation, and will convert operands to strings if possible to do so.

There's an MSDN entry about [Concatenation operations in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw(VS.80).aspx) that explains it:

> The & Operator (Visual Basic) is defined only for String operands, and it always widens its operands to String, regardless of the setting of Option Strict. The & operator is recommended for string concatenation because it is defined exclusively for strings and reduces your chances of generating an unintended conversion.

Comment: The expressions are not the same even with strings if one of the values is null.

Comment: The MSDN article is about Visual Basic, but I guess this works likewise in VBA? There is no VBA documentation page or is it?

Answer (score 3):

The two expressions are equivalent, but the operators are not. `+` can be used as an arithmetic operator as well as for string concatenation, `&` can only be used for the latter.

Comment: They have differing behaviour, see [`+` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9c5t70w2%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) vs. [`&` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfx50zyk%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Consider a null value concatenated with a string using +