# Is there a more elegant way of adding a variable within an Xpath type command? (VBA)

Tags: xml, vba, parsing

I have a Xpath type command, where I want the [i] embedded in the command to be an updateable integer taken from a variable...

```
Set ActiveASIN = objxmldoc.selectSingleNode("//ns1:GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult[i]/ns1:Product/ns1:Identifiers/ns1:MarketplaceASIN/ns1:ASIN")
```

But the only way I can get this to work is to build up the above command in blocks & then concatenate  ....not elegant at all....

```
firstpart = "//ns1:GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult[" + CStr(i) + "]"
secondpart = "/ns1:Product/ns1:Identifiers/ns1:MarketplaceASIN/ns1:ASIN"
complete = firstpart + secondpart
Set ActiveASIN = objxmldoc.selectSingleNode(complete)
```

...is it just a case of me not knowing the correct syntax or does it have to be done as I've done above?

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo, but are you aware that string concatenation is really done using `&` and not `+` ? See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/gg278870.aspx

Comment: concatenation in vba can be performed with + or & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365197/vba-difference-between-and

Comment: in VBA you are kind of limited as far as "elegance" goes. you could use split() and join() together, you could use Replace() or you can use the concatenation operator as you use in your code. https://blog.udemy.com/vba-string-functions/

Comment: @montewhizdoh: Correct but ambiguous. In the posted question, there is at least one integer involved, making the use of `+` risky already. Using CStr(i) to force sting concat while using the wrong operator is more useless code. Just use `&` and a plain `i`; See my answer below.

Comment: I think its important to concede here that the & is definitely more appropriate that the + for string concatenation. Especially if one of the values being concatenated happens to be a NULL value. And, in VBA you do have a few other options for string manipulation, as I mentioned.

Comment: point taken...the reason I used a + is becuase I use MS access a lot & (from recollection) only a + works when entering SQL commands - so in other words an "&" doesn't work across al the interfaces I use....whereas + does! (it means I don't have to think - thinking hurts)

Answer (score 0):

The only alternative I can think of is using `objxmldoc.selectNodes()` to select all of the nodes (without using the [i]) into a nodelist and later use the index of the collection to get the item you wanted.

Something like this:

```
Set ASINNodes = objxmldoc.selectNodes("//ns1:GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult/ns1:Product/ns1:Identifiers/ns1:MarketplaceASIN/ns1:ASIN")
Set ActiveASIN = ASINNodes(i)
```

Depending on your XML and how many i's you need to retrieve, it may be more or less efficient than your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to simpilfy your code, I suggest:

```
Set ActiveASIN = objxmldoc.selectSingleNode( _
                 "//ns1:GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult[" & i & "]" & _
                 "/ns1:Product/ns1:Identifiers/ns1:MarketplaceASIN/ns1:ASIN")
```

Comment: Thanks...that's exactly what I was seeking :-)